# Drag a file from desktop into expanded Dock Folder stack?

Tags: macos, finder, dock, desktop

I was cleaning up my desktop today and wanted to move a file from desktop to the a sub-folder of a Dock Folder, set to "Stack" mode.

I can drag the file onto the Dock, but it expands in a boring, not useful way alphabetically. If I click the stack to expand, it shows me a useful grid sorted by modification date, but when I click the desktop file, it closes.

I'd like to either get the expanded stack to stick open, or the drag operation to trigger the normal, useful stack expansion.

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.3  BuildVersion:  16D32